# Calculating investment duration in Java using simple interest formula

Tags: java, loops, finance, rate, computational-finance

So the task that Im trying to do is to find the number of years taken for a principal to reach a certain value. say for example I start with $5000 and I want to accumulate $15000 with 10% interest rate/year. I want to find how long is the duration of that investment

this is what I have done so far

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class InvestmentDuration {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println ("Initial Investment: ");
    double investment = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println ("Rate as decimals: ");
    double rate = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println ("Future Value: ");
    double FutureValue = input.nextDouble();

    double T = 0; //Initialise Duration//

    double EndValue = investment * Math.pow ((1+rate), T); //Formula of Simple Interest//

     while (EndValue < FutureValue) {
        T += 1.0;

         if (investment * Math.pow((1 + rate), T) == FutureValue);

        System.out.println("The Number of years it takes to accumulate $" + FutureValue + " is " + T + " years");
    }


}
```

output:

```
The Number of years it takes to accumulate $15000.0 is 1.0 years
The Number of years it takes to accumulate $15000.0 is 2.0 years
The Number of years it takes to accumulate $15000.0 is 3.0 years
The Number of years it takes to accumulate $15000.0 is 4.0 years
The Number of years it takes to accumulate $15000.0 is 5.0 years
The Number of years it takes to accumulate $15000.0 is 6.0 years
The Number of years it takes to accumulate $15000.0 is 7.0 years
The Number of years it takes to accumulate $15000.0 is 8.0 years
The Number of years it takes to accumulate $15000.0 is 9.0 years
The Number of years it takes to accumulate $15000.0 is 10.0 years
The Number of years it takes to accumulate $15000.0 is 11.0 years
The Number of years it takes to accumulate $15000.0 is 12.0 years
```

how do I print just the last line?

Comment: @Yusuf Ning Don't use double, use BigDecimal instead!!! double/float are not intended for financial/calculation use.

Comment: [Learn to format your code and name your variables according to the Java Style Guide. Where the leading brace goes is a religious battle, other than that everything else is spot on.](https://github.com/twitter/commons/blob/master/src/java/com/twitter/common/styleguide.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a loop (`for` or `while`). In this loop you can increment the the year and calculate the new value.

Note that I did some changes to the variables:

- Since you wanted to an integer loop, the type of `T` is `int`
- I changed `EndValue` and `FinalValue` to `endValue` and `finalValue` respectively. The Java naming conventions are camelCase with small first letter for variable names.
- I think `years` is a better name than `T`, but that's my personal opinion. If you decide to stay with `T`, at least it should be a small letter `t`

Then you can use the following code. Saving endValue in a variable is not really necessary, since it is used only once. So it could be inlined. But I decided to stay close to your question.

```
    int years = 0;

    double endValue = investment;

    while (endValue < futureValue) {
        years++;
        endValue = investment * Math.pow((1 + rate), years);
    }
```

You should be aware that after this loop, years is the number of full years where `endValue` is greater than or equal to futureValue. That means you can't have something like 3.5 years as result. If you want to calculate that, you should use the solution of Henry.

Comment: One could simplify this a bit by doing `endValue *= 1 + rate;`. But this does not really matter in this application.

Comment: @SilverNak I have done similar to yours. But instead of printing just one line it print the whole line. can you check my code what i did wrong and what to fix so it just print the last line?

Comment: @YusufNing the `System.out.println(...)` should not be in the loop. Place it after the closing `}` of the `while` and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution is with a bit of mathematics:

```
Math.log(goal/start) / Math.log(1+rate/100.0)
```

where `goal` and `start`is the amount at the end and at the beginning respectively and `rate` is the interest rate in percent.

Comment: this is what i did     double T = double (Math.log(FutureValue/investment) /  Math.log (1 + rate)); but it didnt work

Comment: Why did you write `double( ... )` around the formula? Just remove that.

Answer (score 0):

Lots wrong here...
Firstly, your IF statement : It has no action because you have closed it with a semi-colon. Also, endvalue is unlikely to equal futurevalu, partly because of floating point accuracy, and partly because is unlikely to be a whole number of years.
So I would try something like :

```
double T = 0.0;
while(investment * Math.pow ((1+rate), T) < FutureValue) {
   T += 1.0;
}
System.out.println ("The Number of years it takes to accumulate the Future Value is: " +T+);
```

Or you could re-jig the formula to calculate T directly, of course.